# Tools for visualizing and implementing elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: java, cryptography, visualization, plot, elliptic-curve

I need to create a program which will show how elliptic curve cryptography works. I was considering using Java Swing to create the GUI, but the main problem is what tool to use to plot the elliptic curve itself, and how to integrate that with Java Swing.

I would like the plot to be included in the user interface and also allow changes to be made to it. Can you suggest any tools that would help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to get pixels on screen (and still leverage your Java experience) is to use [Processing](http://processing.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to plot elliptic curve in processing from given equation?

Comment: Yes. It's possible to plot a curve in Processing.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider the [Java Function Plotting Library](http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/JavaPlot/) as well.